# How to get current link in InnAppBrowser Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, url

Hi i'm working in Xcode v6.1, Cordova v3.7 , jquerymobile v1.4.5

I have a list in which i have urls of external sites. on clicking any site it will open innappbrowser, i want to navigate in innappbrowser page. for instance i am in index page and after clicking or registeration page how can i get the current url from InnAppBrowser. I know the innAppBrowser exit event but couldnt find current url. here the code

```
function innAppInit(_url) {   
    try {    
        app.Log('browser news link=' + _url);
        if (_url == null) {
            _url = 'http://apache.org';
        }
        var ref = window.open(encodeURI(_url), '_blank', 'location=no');
        console.Dir(ref);
        ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
            $('.ui-loader').hide();
        });
        ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
            alert('exit');
             console.Dir(this);
          // **how to get current url here;**
        });    
    } catch (e) {    
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it in the event of the loadstart, just take it:

```
 var ref = window.open(encodeURI(_url), '_blank', 'location=no');
 ref.addEventListener('exit', function() 
 { 
     alert(event.url);  // here you have the URL
 });
```

See [Cordova docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html) for more info

Comment: alert(event.url);  // here you have the URL returning undefined

Comment: i want url after exit

Comment: use event exit, `ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });` if in the exit event you cannot find url, you should save it in a variable in the previous events, and when exit, use it...